# Using a subject at the end of a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> ***Piled*** higher than head-height on every side ***was mail***. Sacks, satchels,
>   boxes and carts of it, ***spilling*** out onto the cold concrete floor.
>   (Clive Barker, The Great and Secret Show)

I can't understand the construction of these sentences above. Why is "mail" at the end of the sentence, so far from the "piled" and why didn't the author use "were" before "spilling" to make a complete sentence?

I suppose the meaning would remain the same if I rewrote this sentence as in:

> ***Mail was piled*** higher than head-height on every side. Sacks, satchels,
>   boxes and carts of it ***were spilling*** out onto the cold concrete floor.

or

> ***Mail was piled higher*** than head-height on every side, with sacks, satchels, boxes and carts of it ***spilling*** out onto the
>   cold concrete floor.

or

> ***Mail was piled*** higher than head-height on every side, sacks, satchels, boxes and carts of it ***spilling*** out onto the cold
>   concrete floor.

Comment: It's just a different style, placing a little more emphasis on *piled* rather than *mail*, perhaps, but there's no real difference in meaning between these sentences. The last rephrasing doesn't really work with the comma – use a dash or a semicolon instead.

Comment: See inverted sentence, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_sentence